# Babel package not recognized in Gummi in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am trying to write a French report in LaTeX thanks to Gummi editor. I just started it, but I already encounter some unusual issues.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\title{Rapport de stage}
\author{Michaël Tuambilangana}
\date{7 septembre 2015}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I have no idea why my editor won't compile this.
NOTE : I have no problem when instead of "french" for my Babel package, I type "english".

Thank you !

[Edit] Now I have tried to download new packages which might have been missing, I still cannot use my "french" package. Whenever I settle any language else than "english", my output shows this :

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/tmp/.code_source.tex.aux
/tmp/.code_source.tex.aux:2: Package babel Error: Unknown language `english'. E
ither you have
(babel)                misspelled its name, it has not been installed,
(babel)                or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its name,
(babel)                install it or just rerun the file, respectively
```

Whereas when I settle "english"...

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This puzzled me a bit but I think I got it. Knowing more details, like the text of the error message, would have helped.

First, you should try to change

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

to

```
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
```

If this does not solve, then you should check to have the package `babel` updated to the latest version 3.9. Once I updated `babel` (the procedure to do this depends on your system...), I was able to compile with no errors using both option `french` or `frenchb`.

Also, always make sure you know where are the encoding settings of your TeX editor.

There's plenty of good answers about this topic on TeX.SE, starting from:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139700/package-babel-error-unknown-option-francais/139707#139707
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78965/miktex-update-a-too-old-babel-frenchb/78967#78967

and, as you see, depending on the OS etc.

If only option `english` solves, remember to use

```
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! All I had to do was adding french to my "usepackage" section. You saved me. :)